# React-native Routing (single page application)

Tags: react-native, single-page-application, react-router-redux, react-navigation

I am so much confused between react-native routing. I am new to react-native and i never worked on React.js.I want to ask Is react native application is single page application architecture just like angularJs?  there is so many ways for routing and navigation in react-native like

1 .react-native-router-flux

2.Navigator
and many other ways . someone please tell me is this SPA architecture and what is best way for routing in react-native which have more support . I want to make a side drawer menu and tab menu in my app . please help me . thanks in advance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to be clear in the different technologies being used. ReactJS is for building single page `web applications` (similar to `AngularJS`). Where as `React-Native` is developed using the ReactJS framework but it's used for building Native `mobile` apps.

In `React-Native` there is actually no concept of Single page application as everything is developed as a component and these components are used for navigation & routing from one screen to another.

For routing `react-native-router-flux` is extremely simple and easy to use.

You can also check `Nativebase` https://nativebase.io for providing additional components for React native apps with extended functionality including Side Drawer menu and other components. You can also use React-native's inbuilt component `Navigator` if you are trying to build a navigation based app and customize it to either navigator or tab based app style.

Comment: what is native-redux can u guide me ? @Gurdev